# what makes the link between the right/left hands,north/south directions and the duality good-bad

Tags: etymology

Background : I used to think that employing the word "right" to speak about good thinks was only an arabic culture trait - for instance the Quran describes good people with the expression "people of the right" in opposition with "the people of the left" who are the bad ones and when someone is seeing that something bode well or bring good omens we use "يتيمن" which means literally that "he goes right-handed with it",indeed the Arabic word for "right" is "يمين",a word that is also bound to the "south" cardinal direction.

Ironically,the word "omen" with its latin origins but undefined etymology sounds insanely - almost - the same as "يمين" !

When examining the french word "droit" , my intuition becomes just stronger : "droit" that means "right" and comes from the latin "directus"("in straight line") is the same word for "law","wright","jurisdiction","dexterous" and "erect".

When we go further,to say "left" in french we use these days "gauche" but the original word was "senestre" which bears a profound pejorative connotation (yes,it's the word for "sinister")...

It seems that English is not an exception ; "right" comes from the old word "riht" thus "good" while "left" comes from a whole family of pejorative vocabulary (weak,bad...)

Is there any other language (except those derived from Latin or semetic ones) that have the same trait ?

Is this the result of a psychological phenomenon or just a legacy from one very ancestral common language ?

Comment: I think it is a chance that Arabic and French have similar semes for a same morpheme. Because the meaning good in French comes from the meaning straight and not from the spatial position right. The semantic shift in French is probably: spatial position > straight > good. I think in Arabic the path of the semantic shift is different.

Comment: and what about the english case ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection between right (opposite of left) and right (legal term)?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/connection-between-right-opposite-of-left-and-right-legal-term)

Comment: It would help me if you'd transcribe and gloss the Arabic, or at least link each to a dictionary that has it.

Comment: @amegnunsen what makes you think the semantic shift happened *in* French? Is there any evidence of a word for "right (hand (side))" in PIE?

Comment: My say is wrong, the semantic shift is: straight > good > spatial position. Here is the source: https://www.lexilogos.com/document/littre.php?q=Droit

Answer (score 1):

The Latin word omen (< *Ho:-mn) has clear counterparts in Anatolian languages and it has nothing to do with the word yaman.
But you are indeed right that rightside is often linked with good or correct, and leftside with bad or clumsy.

Comment: can you please,share a link for the etymology of "omen" even in anatolian

Comment: I remember Benveniste wrote something about an Anatolian verb ha-, but this was quite long ago. Not sure I can find the reference. I'll try. In Hittite, there's a verb ha- "to hold for true", from which Latin omen "augur, sign" can be derived.

Comment: I'm glad to Iearn about the Hittite word "ha" but the popular etymology of "augur" is from "avis"(bird) which is almost the same as "تطير" in arabic

Comment: Perhaps it's notable that "yaman" is also the primeeval human twin in the vedas, akin to the word *gemini* "twin" The root for avus is rather distant from \*swe ~ \*sew "self", but contains an *-s* at least (in \*Hews if I remember correctly), that might be a remnant of a compound with the aforementioned. Notable only because \*swen- supposedly means "strength, truth", too. I'm not making sense.

Comment: @jihedgasmi: Arnaud Fournet did not claim the augur were etymologically related to *omen*, the use of quotation marks indicates a translation here.

Comment: But how does this etymology explain the (attested!) Old Latin form osmen (see http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=omen&highlight=osmen )?

Comment: **Mod notice:** Some comments have been removed by the mod staff and others were edited in order to remove distracting ad hominems and general unrelated comments. Feel free to express your ideas, but keep it polite. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Persian has this too, as does German. Mongolian and Chinese do not have it, but they use left and right for points of the compass (left is east, right is west)

I think the explanation why many languages have this conection is because in some cultures, you are supposed to keep you right hand clean(er) and use only the left hand for unhygienic stuff.